# how to select all newest records for all users

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a appointment table where i need to select the newest record for all users, currently my query is returning the oldest for each userid instead of the newest one for each

**Appointment table**

```
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID    | time         | userid       | description  |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1     | 2017-10-20   | 4            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2     | 2017-10-21   | 6            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 3     | 2017-10-22   | 7            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 4     | 2017-10-23   | 8            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 5     | 2017-10-24   | 6            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 6     | 2017-10-25   | 7            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**users table**

```
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID    | first        | last         | status       |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 4     | jo           | do           | 1            |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 6     | jid          | did          | 1            |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 7     | jone         | done         | 1            |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 8     | ja           | da           | 1            |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**CURRENT QUERY**

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM appointment 
        LEFT JOIN users AS user
        ON user.id = appointment.userid
        WHERE user.status = 1
        GROUP BY appointment.userid
        ";
```

**CURRENT RESULT**

```
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID    | time         | userid       | description  |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1     | 2017-10-20   | 4            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2     | 2017-10-21   | 6            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 3     | 2017-10-22   | 7            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 4     | 2017-10-23   | 8            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID    | time         | userid       | description  |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1     | 2017-10-20   | 4            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 4     | 2017-10-23   | 8            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 5     | 2017-10-24   | 6            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 6     | 2017-10-25   | 7            | etc          |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: you have a group by but no aggregate function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.ID, a.time, a.userid, a.description 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN appointment a ON u.id = a.userid
WHERE u.status = 1
AND time in(SELECT MAX(time) from appointment t WHERE t.userid = a.userid )
```

Comment: works perfectly, but i have one more question if i want to add a condition for another column `season` in appointment to be met where should i add the `AND` ?

Comment: @mirvatJ You should be able to add it anywhere in the where clause. Did you try adding it?

Comment: yes and i get this error anywhere i add it `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':season AND time is`

Comment: @mirvatJ Can you post your where clause in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a self join to identify the latest appointment:

```
SELECT s.* FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM appointment 
    LEFT JOIN users AS user
     ON user.id = appointment.userid and user.status = 1) s
LEFT JOIN appointment p
 ON(p.userid = s.userid and p.time < s.time)
WHERE p.time IS NULL
```

Though I don't understand why the `LEFT JOIN` to `users` table.

Comment: so it doesnt return an error in case there was a record deleted for a user in the db, what else do u suggest ? also sagi why do u use IS null for time ?

Comment: What? Please try to explain yourself .

Comment: usually when i use inner join and i delete a record lets say from users it returns an error in all the query, but when i use left join it doesn't (probably I might not be right) but it's just something that happened to me before that i am trying to avoid

Comment: It shouldn't throw an error. But it **should** change the output. It really depends what is your requirement.. specificly here, you can just as well write `INNER JOIN` and it will be the same (because of the condition on the `WHERE` clause) . Regardless, does the solution works to you? @mirvatJ

Comment: im getting and error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'p.user_id' in 'on clause' `

Comment: Come on man, that's typo. You can fix those your self. @mirvatJ

Comment: i did change them but i got  `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 's.userid' in 'on clause'`

Comment: i used another method, but i'll vote you up for teaching me something new

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(a.ID) ID, MAX(a.time) time, a.userid, MAX(a.description) description
FROM appointment a
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = a.userid
WHERE u.status = 1
GROUP BY a.userid
ORDER BY a.ID
```

Output

```
ID time                 userid description
1  2017-10-20T00:00:00Z 4      etc
5  2017-10-24T00:00:00Z 6      etc
6  2017-10-25T00:00:00Z 7      etc
4  2017-10-23T00:00:00Z 8      etc
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b0c1c/7/0

Comment: You are relying on the fact the `MAX(time)` will be corresponded with `MAX(id)`, and though in the data sample it looks that way, it won't necessarily be that way .

Comment: @sagi I agree, I would need more sample data to confirm.

Comment: i tried that solution before, but in case when there are integer fields, it will get the highest value instead of the newest

Answer (score 0):

I think the `left join` with user table is unnecessary .
The following query will give the expected result

```
select a1.* from appointment a1
inner join (select max(id) as id ,userid from appointment group by userid) a2
on a1.id=a2.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c23104/6)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT max(appointment.id), max(time), user.id, description
FROM appointment 
LEFT JOIN users AS user
ON user.id = appointment.userid
WHERE user.status = 1
GROUP BY appointment.userid
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, and the left join will transform into an inner join because of your `WHERE` clause.